# How assign a exported global Array of Pointers in JNA

Tags: pointers, jna

I want to use JNA to assign an array of pointers from Java to an "exported global" array of pointers to a structure in a native library.

I have a workaround right now where I created an API function that accepts a pointer to a struct and then makes the assignment natively. This workaround is only acceptable because i have access to the native source code.

In C the global variable:

```
SM_t** SM_REFS;
```

I import the library in JNA:

```
static Pointer SM_REFS = lib.getGlobalVariableAddress("SM_REFS");
```

In the main I attempt to assign to the pointer as:

```
SM2.SM_REFS.setPointer(0, BB.SM.getPointer());  // this will crash
```

How should I do this on the Java side?

---

My workaround was to export a native function and use JNA to pass a structure.

```
SM2.INSTANCE.SET_SM_REFS( BB.SM, 0);
```

This works because on the C side i have:

```
int SET_SM_REFS(SM_t* thisSM, int index){

    SM_REFS[index] = thisSM;
    return 1;

}
```

I would like to do it on the Java side like it would be done in C. Something like

```
SM_REFS[0] = &BB;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Seems that `**` is a Pointer to a Pointer.  Are you sure you don't want `PointerByReference`?    Who is doing the memory management for the array being pointed to?

Comment: Your C code has allocated memory for the array somewhere, and your ** pointer points to a pointer to the beginning of that array.  When you try to overwrite that pointer with another you have not allocated any memory for where the new pointer location directs to.

Comment: I think i found the two issues. 1) When you have a structure in JNA and want to use an "explicit" pointer to the data (in my case because i want to assign the global), you have to use the write() method first. So i would have to do BB.SM.write(); somewhere earlier. Note: If i was using the structure in a function call, JNA does it for me.  2) That only gives me one * to provide but i have **  So the total call to set the exported global SM_REFS** would be "SM2.SM_REFS.getPointer(0).setPointer(0, BB.SM.getPointer())".  Where the first "getPointer(0)" is needed for indirection.